# Random effects perfectly correlated? (nlme package in R)

Tags: r, random

I'm trying to simulate data and then fit a non-linear mixed effects model to it. But in most of the cases my random effects are perfectly correlated, and I don't understand why.And I think this is the reason for the frequently occuring errors (singularity of matrices or the algorithm doesn't converge...)

The figure shows the pairs plot for the random effects.

[image]

The output of the model is given by

```
    [Nonlinear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Model: conc ~ SSmicmen(time, Vm, K) 
  Data: groupedData(conc ~ time | subject, data = sample2) 
  Log-likelihood: -101.3446
  Fixed: Vm + K ~ 1 
      Vm        K 
4.253410 8.732609 

Random effects:
 Formula: list(Vm ~ 1, K ~ 1)
 Level: subject
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
         StdDev    Corr
Vm       1.1218405 Vm  
K        4.1308831 1   
Residual 0.9296998     

Number of Observations: 72
Number of Groups: 12][1]
```

I'm new to NLMEM but this is not a good fit, if there is such a big correlation...? I would not want to reduce the random effects.
 I tried using different covariance matrices for generating the random effects, diagonal, non-diagonal... always the same problem. Can someone give me some explanations? Perhaps the sample size is not big enough?

I create the data like this:

```
 for (m in 1:n1)
    {
      b1=rmvnorm(1,rep(0,2),sigma=S1) #random effect vector
      y1=(5+b1[1])*x/(3+b1[2]+x)+rnorm(length(x),mean=0,sd=sqrt(sigma1))
      gr1[m,]=y1
    }
```

This is a Michalis Menten Model, I have n1 subjects, each measured in x (length of x is 6). The matrix S1 is my assumed variance covariance matrix for the random effects, I tried different ones... then I use this data for creating a grouped data object and then I fit the model:

```
nlme(conc~SSmicmen(time, Vm, K),data=groupedData(conc~time|subject,data=sample1),fixed=Vm+K~1,start=c(Vm=5,K=3),control=nlmeControl(maxIter=2000,opt="nlminb",tolerance=0.00001))
```

Comment: Yes, I put it in my question above due to better readability...

Comment: You'd have a better shot at an answer at the [statistics stack exchange](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried... I have the impression that Im doing something basically wrong.